# Issue while accessing element by dojo.byId dojo 1.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I am trying to access a div element text by using dojo.byId but it is returning the value which is set at first time the value is selected.It is somehow binding the value initially selected to the id of div and hence returning the same value even after I change the value to some other value.

```
var startDateLabel = dojo.byId("startDateLabel");
<label class="secondaryColor bold75Font floatRight" id="startDateLabel">${startDate} </label>
```

I tried to use registry.ById but since it is in a widget that is created more than once , it gives "id already registered error".For removing that , I also used destroyRecursive method but that also doesn't work.

Earlier, I used the id of container in which the widget is loaded and traversed to the children hierarchy to get the label value and it worked fine. but the child traversal code made it a bit messy.Something like 
    var startDateCont = registry.byId("startDateContainer");
    var startDateLabel =   startDateCont.domNode.children[1].children[1].children[1].innerHTML;

Is there any other way in dojo to achive this????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using this inside a widget you should not even use IDs (or at least use generated IDs). The best way to get a reference to a DOM node while using a widget is by using **attach points**. An example, consider the following HTML:

```
<label class="secondaryColor bold75Font floatRight" data-dojo-attach-point="startDateLabel">${startDate} </label>
```

As you can see I introduced an attribtue called `data-dojo-attach-point` which allows me to give a name to the label (similar to an ID).

Then inside the widget you can now easily get a reference to that DOM node by using:

```
this.startDateLabel;
```

---

Just some extra information, you can also define events in a similar way by using `data-dojo-attach-event`. Make sure to read this part of the [Writing your own widget](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#templated-widgets) article.

Comment: Thanks for Info, but in this case I cannot use attach points in this case as the attach point is accessible only inside the widget whereas I have to access this object out of widget code.Apart from attach point or the child node traversal, is there any other way to do this??

Comment: You can access the DOM node from outside of the widget if you use `registry.byId("myWidget").startDateLabel`. It's added as a property to the widget so everyone can access it. However, usually in OOP you should try to encapsulate it.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, however I am unable to understand how to use the id of widget.When i created a custom widget, it did not create any id.Which is this id, is it the name of widget???

Comment: If you don't specify an ID while creating an instance of your widget, it's automatically generated, usually based on the `declaredClass` or the name of the first parameter inside your `declare()`. If you didn't provide any of these, then the ID is something like `uniqName__0`. But you don't actually need an ID, look at http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/registry.html for other methods to retrieve your widget instance. If you programmatically created your widget you should already be able to access it without using `dijit/registry`.